# static shortcut android don't appear

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-shortcut

I try to add a shortcut to my application, but when I do a long click I don't see it.

I double checked my application id, also the activity.

Here is what I try.

My shortcut.xml :

```
  <shortcut
    android:shortcutId="conso"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_budgeting"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_conso_short"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_conso_long"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/shortcut_conso_dissable_message">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.****.stubs_dev.debug"
        android:targetClass="com.******iviConsoActivity" />
    <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
         here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
         they launch this shortcut. -->

</shortcut>
```

on manifest i add

on application and on activity i add also android:exported="true"

what's wrong with my code ?

EDIT here my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="****">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



<application
    android:name="....."
    android:icon="@mipmap/..."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="icon">
```

....

```
   <!-- Shortcuts-->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
        android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
</application>
```

My activity declaration :

```
   <activity
        android:name=".****onsoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Is that the whole contents of `shortcut.xml`? It needs to be wrapped in `<shortcuts></shortcuts>` tag

Comment: Can you also paste your manifest snippet where you adding the `shortcut.xml`?

Comment: i just posted manifest

Comment: @lyrjie i have <shortcuts></shortcuts> in my original  file

Comment: Please double-check that the file name is `shortcuts.xml` with s in the end. In your post it is referred as `shortcut.xml`

Comment: @lyrjie his name is shortcuts.xml yes :(

Comment: I think the problem is that your `<meta-data>` tag is inside `<application>`, not `activity`, judging by indent

Comment: i add them on application and on activity

Comment: @lyrjie you think i must delete meta data from application and keep only activity ?

Comment: @tamtoum1987 yes

Comment: @lyrjie i just try it i have still the same problem :(

Comment: @lyrjie i thought i has to add this meta-data on activity i redirect to when i click on this item shortcut, but when i add meta data in main activity it's work thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your xml name is `shortcuts.xml` then make sure you are adding `shortcuts.xml` to the launcher Activity that has the `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` intent filters.
Let's assume it is `MainActivity` then it would look like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
       android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

Comment: what i need to add this on android.intent.category.LAUNCHER activity ?

Comment: i thought i need to add this meta-data on activity  i redirect to when i click on this item shortcut

Comment: No, only main activities—activities that handle the `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` action and` Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` category—can have shortcuts. 
Because Activities with these intents are visible to the user in the launcher